# Безответные запросы , возвращение

Tags: php, sql, запрос

Есть к примеру запросы

```
UPDATE `users` SET `money` = money - $price WHERE `id` = 5;
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 5;
INSERT INTO `users`(id, login) VALUES(5, 'login');
```

Если в пхп не будет ошибок с функциями отправки и т.д тогда мне в любом случае возвратится true

Даже если у меня будет не правильно написано название колонки, или значение.

Можно ли как то отследить SQL ошибки в пхп?

Comment: вы бы пример кода на php привели, может вы не так этим пользуетесь? для update/insert/delete должно true возвращаться только в случае успешного выполнения, т.е. если была ошибка, должно вернуть false

Comment: Вы попробуйте через пхп отдать запрос на удаление к примеру записи из таблицы, Вам вернет true, что будет означать что запрос отдался на обработку sql (как мне объясняли)

Comment: `TRUE` - будет означать, что запрос составлен верно и был выполнен (кстати это совершенно не означает, что в таблицу будут внесены изменения). Что вас смущает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не можно, а нужно. Только вы не указали какую библиотеку вы используете для работы с MySQL, поэтому рассмотрю несколько вариантов.

В общем случае обработку ошибок при запросах к базе следует выполнять в виде [исключений](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php).

Если вы используете *php_mysql* или *php_mysqli*, то после выполнения запроса с ошибкой функциями `mysql_query()`, `mysqli_query()` или `mysqli_stmt_execute()` вы получите FALSE. При этом можно бросить исключение:

```
$mysqliStmt->execute() or throw new Exception($mysqli->error, $mysqli->errno);
```

Также рекомендую для исключений при работе с базой определить отдельно свой класс, порожденный от [Exception](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.exception.php).

В *php_pdo* все это есть "из коробки". Чтобы при возникновении ошибок бросались исключения достаточно после создания экземпляра класса [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.pdo.php) указать способ обработки ошибок:

```
$pdoConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

При этом, в случае возникновения ошибок будет бросаться исключение типа [PDOException](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.pdoexception.php).